# Address several variables with one command

Tags: r

I have a variable called "Retired" in the Dataset plants which indicates in which year a coal fired power plant retired. I would like to create a dummy variable that tells me 0 = in operation, 1 = Retired. For this I have the following code:

```
> plants$Retired_dummy <- ifelse(plants$Retired == "2000" |
> plants$Retired == "2001" | plants$Retired == "2002"| plants$Retired ==
> "2003"| plants$Retired == "2004"| plants$Retired == "2005"|
> plants$Retired == "2006"| plants$Retired == "2007"| plants$Retired ==
> "2008"| plants$Retired == "2009"| plants$Retired == "2010"|
> plants$Retired == "2011"| plants$Retired == "2012"| plants$Retired ==
> "2013"| plants$Retired == "2014"| plants$Retired == "2015"|
> plants$Retired == "2016"| plants$Retired == "2017"| plants$Retired ==
> "2018"| plants$Retired == "2019"| plants$Retired == "2020"|
> plants$Retired == "2021" | plants$Retired == "2022" , 1, 0)
```

For the next variable "Retire planned" I would like to do the same, but I have years from 2020-2070 and do not want to enter them all individually. Is there a way to tell RStudio to address all variable names from 2020-2070?

Comment: Use `%in%` instead, `ifelse(plants$Retired %in% c("2000", "2001"....), 1, 0)`

Comment: If you convert the years into numeric then we could do: `ifelse(as.numeric(plants$Retired) %in% 2000:2022, 1, 0)`